# Recursive Pagination in CakePHP Not Working

Tags: cakephp, recursion, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I apologize if this question has been asked and answered elsewhere but I have looked and have not been able to find it.

I have three models:
`Manager` HABTM `Tenant`

I also have a `ManagersTenant` model to tie the two together.

I'm trying to use pagination to recursively display fields from `Manager` and `Tenant` in the `ManagersTenant` controller.  Here is my code:

`$this->ManagersTenant->recursive = 2;`

`$this->set('managersTenants', $this->paginate('ManagersTenant',array(),array('recursive'=>2)));`

This displays only the fields in `ManagersTenant` (`id`, `tenant_id`, `manager_id`) but does not retrieve data from the associated `Manager` and `Tenant` models.

I am also doing a `debug($this->ManagersTenant->find('all'));` which performs the recursion perfectly and displays the right arrays.

What am I doing wrong?  Do I need to do anything special with my model(s)?

Any help is much appreciated.

//edit:

What I'm trying to do is display all matches where `Tenant_id` or `Manager_id` matches the logged-in user's id.  For example, if a logged-in `Manager` performs the `index` function on the `Tenant` model, I would like for all `Tenants` to be displayed for `Tenant_id` where `Manager_id` (in the `ManagersTenant` model) == `$this->Auth->User('id')`.  I was under the impression that in order to do this, I had to utilize a HABTM table.  But if it is possible for me to do `Manager` HABTM `Tenant` without a joining table, I am all for trying it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to define the ManagersTenant model. You should define [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM) in the Manager and in the Tenant model, and use those models for your query.

If you really need a ManagersTenant model you should use the [join model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1650/hasMany-through-The-Join-Model) relationship:

- Manager hasMany ManagersTenant
- Tenant hasMany ManagersTenant
- ManagersTenant belongsTo Manager and Tenant.

Comment: I thought I had to have a `ManagersTenant` model to handle the `Manager` HABTM `Tenant` relationship.  I will definitely have a need for a join model in other parts of the app, but I was hoping recursion would simply pull the data from the associated models.  It seems to work when I do a find() so why not with pagination?

Comment: I tried your suggestion to use the `Tenant` model instead of the `ManagersTenant` model and recursion seems to be working.  The only problem now is that `containable` does not seem to work.

Comment: containable should work with HABTM, check the examples: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1323/Containable